# Getting reference issue in Qt while implementing OpenSceneGraph

Tags: c++, qt, openscenegraph

I am getting error (**

**> CMakeFiles\untitled3.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text+0x46):

> undefined reference to `_imp___ZN9osgViewer6ViewerC1Ev'**)

while adding OpenSceneGraph in Qt. My profile is cmakelist.txt.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)

project(untitled3)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

find_package(Qt5Core)
FIND_PATH(OPENSCENEGRAPH_INCLUDE_DIR osg/Referenced
    PATHS
    $ENV{OSG_ROOT}/include
    $ENV{OSG_DIR}/include
    /usr/include
    /usr/local/include
)

FIND_PATH(OPENSCENEGRAPH_LIB_DIR libosg.so osg.lib
    PATHS
    $ENV{OSG_ROOT}/lib
    $ENV{OSG_DIR}/lib
    /usr/lib
    /usr/local/lib
)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(common ${OPENSCENEGRAPH_INCLUDE_DIR})
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${OPENSCENEGRAPH_LIB_DIR})

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Core)
```

My main.cpp file is

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <osgViewer/Viewer>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    osgViewer::Viewer viewer;
//       viewer.setSceneData( osgDB::readNodeFile("cessna.osg") );
//       return viewer.run();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Any folks who can help. I invite them to come forward.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your cmake file. You need to make sure to:

1. Find the necessary OSG packages (osgViewer in your case).
2. Link your executable to the target OSG libraries.

Just like you did it for QtCore:

```
find_package(Qt5Core)
find_package(OpenSceneGraph REQUIRED COMPONENTS osgViewer)
# ...
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Core  ${OPENSCENEGRAPH_LIBRARIES} )
```